# How to calculate x and y for a rythem music game notes from a midi json file

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have never created a game a before and I am thinking of developing one now.

The game I am thinking o creating is a rythem game, kinda of like gitar hero.

So the first think I hade to do is gettings the notes of an mp3 file.

and this is what I got.

```json
{
    "header": {
        "PPQ": 46,
        "bpm": 120,
        "name": ""
    },
    "tempo": [{
            "absoluteTime": 0,
            "seconds": 0,
            "bpm": 120
        }
    ],
    "timeSignature": [],
    "startTime": 0,
    "duration": 279.08695652187913,
    "tracks": [{
            "startTime": 0,
            "duration": 279.08695652187913,
            "length": 29841,
            "notes": [{
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 0,
                    "velocity": 0.11811023622047244,
                    "duration": 0.21739130434782608
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 0.32608695652173914,
                    "velocity": 0.14960629921259844,
                    "duration": 0.09782608695652173
                }, {
                    "name": "C#3",
                    "midi": 49,
                    "time": 0.6304347826086957,
                    "velocity": 0.07874015748031496,
                    "duration": 0.07608695652173914
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 0.7065217391304348,
                    "velocity": 0.07086614173228346,
                    "duration": 0.03260869565217395
                }, {
                    "name": "C#5",
                    "midi": 73,
                    "time": 0.891304347826087,
                    "velocity": 0.09448818897637795,
                    "duration": 0.08695652173913049
                }, {
                    "name": "C#3",
                    "midi": 49,
                    "time": 1.0543478260869565,
                    "velocity": 0.14173228346456693,
                    "duration": 0.5326086956521743
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 1.1521739130434783,
                    "velocity": 0.13385826771653545,
                    "duration": 0.11956521739130443
                }, {
                    "name": "C#5",
                    "midi": 73,
                    "time": 1.173913043478261,
                    "velocity": 0.12598425196850394,
                    "duration": 0.10869565217391308
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 1.3913043478260871,
                    "velocity": 0.12598425196850394,
                    "duration": 0.20652173913043503
                }, {
                    "name": "C#5",
                    "midi": 73,
                    "time": 1.5108695652173916,
                    "velocity": 0.11023622047244094,
                    "duration": 0.0652173913043479
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 1.695652173913044,
                    "velocity": 0.14960629921259844,
                    "duration": 0.17391304347826075
                }, {
                    "name": "C#3",
                    "midi": 49,
                    "time": 2.021739130434783,
                    "velocity": 0.14173228346456693,
                    "duration": 0.5326086956521738
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 2.0326086956521743,
                    "velocity": 0.18110236220472442,
                    "duration": 0.1304347826086958
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 2.5108695652173916,
                    "velocity": 0.11811023622047244,
                    "duration": 0.20652173913043503
                }, {
                    "name": "C#3",
                    "midi": 49,
                    "time": 2.7826086956521743,
                    "velocity": 0.16535433070866143,
                    "duration": 0.9347826086956523
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 2.8695652173913047,
                    "velocity": 0.13385826771653545,
                    "duration": 0.1521739130434785
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 3.1304347826086962,
                    "velocity": 0.15748031496062992,
                    "duration": 0.46739130434782616
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 3.760869565217392,
                    "velocity": 0.13385826771653545,
                    "duration": 0.14130434782608692
                }, {
                    "name": "C#3",
                    "midi": 49,
                    "time": 3.9239130434782616,
                    "velocity": 0.14173228346456693,
                    "duration": 0.2065217391304346
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 3.9239130434782616,
                    "velocity": 0.16535433070866143,
                    "duration": 0.16304347826086918
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 4.119565217391305,
                    "velocity": 0.2677165354330709,
                    "duration": 0.3913043478260869
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 4.543478260869565,
                    "velocity": 0.1889763779527559,
                    "duration": 0.06521739130434767
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 4.630434782608695,
                    "velocity": 0.2677165354330709,
                    "duration": 0.7065217391304346
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 5.434782608695651,
                    "velocity": 0.30708661417322836,
                    "duration": 0.6847826086956523
                }, {
                    "name": "G#4",
                    "midi": 68,
                    "time": 6.152173913043478,
                    "velocity": 0.2047244094488189,
                    "duration": 0.23913043478260843
                }, {
                    "name": "C#3",
                    "midi": 49,
                    "time": 6.2934782608695645,
                    "velocity": 0.10236220472440945,
                    "duration": 0.09782608695652151
                }, 
            ],
            "controlChanges": {},
            "id": 0,
            "instrumentNumber": 0,
            "instrument": "acoustic grand piano",
            "instrumentFamily": "piano",
            "channelNumber": 0,
            "isPercussion": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Now how can I convert the notes to `x` , `y` and `speed`

something like below json

```json
const balls =[
{
  x: number,
  y: number,
  speed: number
}
]
```

I could not find any lesson on how to calculate them.

I want to build this in react-native and this is really a challenge for me.

If you could point me in the right direction or maybe tell me how is it possible to convert the notes would be really helpful